# How to predict top 1% grades in an exam with only pass mark and percentage who passed

Tags: distributions

I am trying to figure out what the top 1% of marks are for a set of past exams, where I only have the passing mark of 58% and the percentage of people who passed. 45%.

I want to use the normal distribution to estimate the grade achieved by the top 1% of students who passed. So assuming the student's marks are normally distributed and 45% of people scored 58/100 or more.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The information is not sufficient. You only know that the mark of the 55-th percentile is 58/100. But you do not know anything about the spread.

Comment: Not only don't you have enough information to estimate what normal distribution it is (see answer of @SextusEmpiricus ), neither do you have any information (in the given datum) to asses whether the normal distribution is any good as a model here.

Comment: I think you need a `self-study` tag on this Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, @SextusEmpiricus (+1) and @ChristianHenning are quite correct that this is
a silly, impossible problem---at least without making possibly unwarranted assumptions. But
assuming test scores to be roughly normally distributed is standard fare
in elementary probability problems.

Granted that it is reasonable to assume/guess that scores are normally distributed, you might also assume/guess that the top possible z-score (corresponding to 100%) is $3.$ [The Empirical Rule might suggest $3.]$ Then, together with the given 45th percentile, you can get two equations in two unknowns $\mu$ and $\sigma.$  Roughly, say $\mu = 59.7, \sigma = 13.44$ are their solution.

Then in R, you'd have:

```
pnorm(c(58,91,100), 59.7, 13.44)
[1] 0.4496728 0.9900670 0.9986435
```

Maybe it's not too much of a reach to say that the 99th percentile is about $91.$
You may want to make some refinements to the details, but I guess something like this might be what was expected by way of solution.

*Note:* Clearly my choice of $3,$ to which some commenters object with surprising vehemence, is
somewhat arbitrary, and I have clearly labeled it is a guess. But it's not *completely* arbitrary if you want the answer to make sense: for example, it wouldn't have been reasonable or productive to choose $2$ or $4.$

Comment: "you might also assume/guess that the top possible z-score (corresponding to 100%) is 3" - this essentially *assumes* the solution rather than deriving it from the given information - the solution is entirely dominated by the choice you make here, for which reason I wouldn't agree that 3 is any more natural than any other choice. At least, in my opinion, it doesn't make sense to expect any particular choice of this kind in an "elementary probability problem" of this kind, for which reason I don't think it's a "self study" problem.

Comment: Over about 60 years of teaching, I have seen a lot of probability problems that state, invite, or require far-fetched assumptions. This one is nowhere near the 91st percentile on my 'silliness' scale.

Comment: BTW it wasn't me who voted this down. Besides, the thing is not so much that a far fetched assumption is required, rather that this assumption is what determines the solution.

Comment: I downvoted it. And more people clearly should have because it’s the answer OP chose as the correct answer even though as Christian points out, it’s clearly the inferior answer for a few different reasons. But you gave OP a number so they ignored the other correct answer and chose this flawed incorrect answer

Comment: @BruceET Explain how your answer is any more reasonable or productive than an answer such as μ=58.12, σ=1 and 99% of 60.45 (or any other number of possibilities) and I will remove my down vote. Your statement the Empirical rule suggests 3 makes no sense to me here.

Comment: @astel. Not claiming my answer if the very best. But maybe a little better than your suggestion, Only claiming that my general approach might be reasonable, given that incomplete info is provided.  Invited OP to make refinements. Having trouble understanding the unusually strong opinions on this. Maybe it's really true that the strength of opinions is inversely proportional to the importance of the issue.

Comment: Explain how your suggestion is any better than mine? My problem is that you aren't providing any justification at all.

Comment: For one thing, your test has essentially no scores above 65 out of 100. Fortunately, not many instructors give such demoralizing tests. // For me this is the end of a discussion that seems to be going nowhere. And we are about to get busted for chatting in Comments.

Answer (score 3):

The information is not sufficient. You only know that the mark of the 55-th percentile is 58/100. But you do not know anything about the spread. Below you see the distribution of different normal distributions that have the same 58 score for the 55-th percentile (the score where 45% do better than that), but different scores for the 99-th percentile (the score of the best 1%).

The image below shows the cumulative distribution. It gives on the x-axis the score, and on the y-axis the percentage that has this score or lower.

[image: example]

Sidenote: even if you knew two points, the  an estimate based on the assumption that the distribution is a normal distribution can be very wrong. Normal distributions might be good models for an average, but distributions like scores on a test involve different processes that generate the distribution. E.g. you can have students that studied and students that did not study, splitting the distribution into two groups and making the distribution bimodal.